# Is it true that every scc is the union of cycles

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $S$ is a strongly connected component of a digraph, then $S$ is the union of cycles of it's vertices, I conjecture. Is this true? I can nowhere find such a statement.

Comment: I know about connected graphs and strongly connected digraphs, but a graph is strongly connected if...

Comment: I meant digraphs! I will edit.

Comment: Given an arc, can you see that there is a (directed) cycle containing it?

Comment: yes, and given two vertices from an scc, i see that they are contained in an cycle, so thats why I conjectured it, but nowwhere is it written in textbooks, so I got unsure

Answer (score 1):

I think the conjecture need not be true.  Take the digraph $S$ to be the directed 4-cycle graph plus one more arc. Thus the edge set would be $\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(2,4)\}$.  This digraph is strongly connected because of the presence of the directed 4-cycle, but to violate the property that the edge set is the union of directed-cycles, just add that last arc.